# How to perform sort on all files in a directory?

Tags: file, unix, sorting, directory, cat

How do I perform sort on all files in the directory?

I could have done it in python, but it seems to be too much of a hassle.

```
import os, glob
d = '/somedir/'

for f in glob.glob(d+"*"):
  f2 = f+".tmp"
  # unix~$ cat f | sort > f2; mv f2 f
  os.system("cat "+f+" | sort > "+f2+"; mv "+f2+" "+f)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `find` and `-exec`:

```
find /somedir -type f -exec sort -o {} {} \;
```

For limiting the `sort` to the files in the directory itself, use `-maxdepth`:

```
find /somedir -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sort -o {} {} \;
```

Comment: Will this output a separate file for each input file in the folder? And how can I make it so that the output files go to a subdirectory rather than the parent that contains the original files?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
directory="/home/user/somedir"
if [ ! -d $directory ]; then
  echo "Error: Directory doesn't exist"
  exit 1
fi
for file in $directory/*
do
  if [ -f $file ]; then
      cat $file | sort > $file.tmp
      mv -f  $file.tmp $file
  fi
done
```

Comment: From the script of the question owner, I see that he wanted to sort file content, not file names. I don't understand why your answer is not marked as accepted.